# UITableView custom cell height is not properly managing for dynamic constraints in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

> I am having table view and took the custom cell from xib, I have lots
>   of things to expand in the cell when there is media or bigger text, I
>   have managed the height programmatically in the delegate method and
>   constraint in the cell as well But sometimes when I open the app and
>   load the data the cell gets overlapped but when I scroll up-down then
>   it looks fine. What can I do to get that updated immediately after
>   reloading when I get data from API?

[image]

**I think there is no issue in code since it works after refreshing again or scrolling the table view.
height delegate method is below:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    let newsDict = self.tableDataNewsArray[indexPath.section]
    let newsDataArray = newsDict["news"] as! [NewsBriefModel]
    let newsObject = newsDataArray[indexPath.item]

    if (self.moreExpandableArray.firstIndex(of: newsObject.newsbrief_id) != nil) {
        return 62 + 58 + 4 + 62 //(62:// label minimum height )(46: other than label caponents in cell :: 4: spacing
        // 62: more/less button view height)

    }else if (self.lessExpandableArray.firstIndex(of: newsObject.newsbrief_id) != nil) {

        var baseMoreHeight : CGFloat = newsObject.labelHeightForPostText + 58 + 4 + 62 //(46: other than label caponents in cell :: 4: spacing
        // 62: more/less button view height)

        if newsObject.numberOfImagesInPost > 0 {
            baseMoreHeight = baseMoreHeight + 110
        }
        if newsObject.numberOfDocumentInPost > 0 {
            baseMoreHeight = baseMoreHeight + CGFloat((newsObject.numberOfDocumentInPost * 45))
        }
        if newsObject.numberOfVideosInPost > 0 {
            baseMoreHeight = baseMoreHeight + CGFloat((newsObject.numberOfVideosInPost * 100))
        }

        return baseMoreHeight
    }

}
```

**Cell Methods which I call in cellForRow to change the UI:**

```
 // MARK: CELL METHODS

    func showNormalView() {

        self.postTitleLabel.numberOfLines = 3
        self.postTitleTextView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 3
        self.postTitleTextView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail

        self.mediaViewHeight.constant = 0
        self.documentTableViewHeight.constant = 0
        self.videoTableViewHeight.constant = 0
        self.multiMediaView.isHidden = true
        self.loadImages(urlString: [])
        self.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
        self.setNeedsLayout()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    func showMoreView() {

        self.postTitleLabel.numberOfLines = 3
        self.postTitleTextView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 3
        self.postTitleTextView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail

        self.mediaViewHeight.constant = 50
        self.imageGridViewHeight.constant = 0
        self.documentTableViewHeight.constant = 0
        self.videoTableViewHeight.constant = 0
        self.loadImages(urlString: [])
        self.multiMediaView.isHidden = false
        self.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
        self.setNeedsLayout()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

Comment: You should debug the view hierarchy in Xcode, to check what `unwanted` view is displayed.

Comment: I think cell constraint is not proper.

Comment: @Paresh.P if that was the things then it may have the issue all time, the issue is only first time.. after i scroll or refresh again then it shows properly

Comment: @AndreasOetjen yeah i tried the things is tableview cell height is not increasing.

Comment: Can you please describe more with cellforrow code and datasource?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use UITableView.automaticDimension instead of calculating height manually, and use delegate pattern to update cell's height.

Here is what i've got with this approach:

[image]

and code example:

```
import UIKit

struct Content {
  let author: String
  let date: String
  let views: UInt
  let recs: UInt
  let content: String
}

let longText = """
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
"""

protocol MyCellDelegate: AnyObject {
  func contentDidChange(cell: UITableViewCell)
}

final class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
  static let reuseIdentifier = "MyCell"

  weak var delegate: MyCellDelegate?

  private var viewsCountLabel: UILabel!
  private var recsLabel: UILabel!
  private var authorLabel: UILabel!
  private var dateLabel: UILabel!
  private var contentLabel: UILabel!
  private var toggleHeightButton: UIButton!

  override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    setupSubviews()
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("not implemented")
  }

  override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    viewsCountLabel.text = nil
    recsLabel.text = nil
    authorLabel.text = nil
    dateLabel.text = nil
    contentLabel.text = nil
    contentLabel.numberOfLines = 2
  }

  public func setContent(_ content: Content) {
    viewsCountLabel.text = "Views: \(content.views)"
    recsLabel.text = "Recs: \(content.recs)"
    authorLabel.text = content.author
    dateLabel.text = content.date
    contentLabel.text = content.content
  }

  private func setupSubviews() {
    let leftStackView = createLeftStack()
    let rightStackView = createRightStack()

    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [leftStackView, rightStackView])
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.spacing = 5
    stackView.alignment = .top

    contentView.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
      stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
      stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 3),
      stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -3)
    ])
  }

  private func createLeftStack() -> UIStackView {
    let iconView = createIconView()
    viewsCountLabel = createLabel()
    recsLabel = createLabel()
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [iconView, viewsCountLabel, recsLabel])
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.setCustomSpacing(4, after: iconView)
    stackView.alignment = .leading
    return stackView
  }

  private func createRightStack() -> UIStackView {
    authorLabel = createLabel()
    dateLabel = createLabel()
    contentLabel = UILabel()
    contentLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .bold)
    contentLabel.contentMode = .topLeft

    toggleHeightButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    toggleHeightButton.setTitle("Toggle", for: .normal)
    toggleHeightButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(expandDidTap), for: .touchUpInside)
    toggleHeightButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true

    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [authorLabel, dateLabel, contentLabel, toggleHeightButton])
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.alignment = .leading
    return stackView
  }

  private func createIconView() -> UIView {
    let iconView = UIView()
    iconView.backgroundColor = .blue
    iconView.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    iconView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 8)
    label.numberOfLines = 2
    label.text = "Upload Icon"
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.textColor = .white
    iconView.addSubview(label)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    iconView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconView.leadingAnchor, constant: 3),
      label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconView.trailingAnchor, constant: -3),
      label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconView.topAnchor, constant: 3),
      label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconView.bottomAnchor, constant: -3),
      iconView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
      iconView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
    ])
    return iconView
  }

  private func createLabel() -> UILabel {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 8, weight: .light)
    label.numberOfLines = 1
    return label
  }

  @objc func expandDidTap() {
    let isExpand = contentLabel.numberOfLines != 0
    if isExpand {
      contentLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    } else {
      contentLabel.numberOfLines = 2
    }
    delegate?.contentDidChange(cell: self)
  }
}

final class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
  private var tableView: UITableView {
    view as! UITableView
  }

  private var data: [Content] = [] {
    didSet {
      tableView.reloadData()
    }
  }

  override func loadView() {
    let tableView = UITableView()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(MyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: MyCell.reuseIdentifier)
    view = tableView
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
      self.data = [
        Content(author: "Author1", date: "15:07", views: 2, recs: 1, content: longText),
        Content(author: "Author2", date: "15:07", views: 2, recs: 1, content: longText),
        Content(author: "Author3", date: "15:07", views: 2, recs: 1, content: longText),
        Content(author: "Author1", date: "15:07", views: 2, recs: 1, content: longText)
      ]
    }
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    data.count
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MyCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCell
    cell.delegate = self
    let content = data[indexPath.row]
    cell.setContent(content)
    return cell
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
  }
}

extension MyViewController: MyCellDelegate {
  func contentDidChange(cell: UITableViewCell) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
      self.tableView.beginUpdates()
      self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it’s better to use `UITableView.automaticDimension` and also make sure you set `estimatedRowHeight` and besides that make sure the last element in the cell has bottom constraint with the `ContentView` of the `Cell`